# Better way to remove character from index column in this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my approach right now, but I'm thinking there is maybe a better way to do it?

The data looks like this:

```
                       2018 Population
Location                              
United States                327167434
.Alabama                       4887871
.Alaska                         737438
.Arizona                       7171646
```

I want it like this:

```
                           2018 Population
Location                              
United States                327167434
Alabama                       4887871
Alaska                         737438
Arizona                       7171646
```

Here is my code (which works), but like I said I think there might be a better way?

```
index_vals = df_census.index.values
i = 0
for index_val in index_vals:
    index_vals[i] = index_val.replace(".","")
    i += 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `index.str.strip`

```
df_census.index = df_census.index.str.strip('.')
```